# I'm learning more of JavaScript and I want to have some idea about this code

Tags: javascript

I'm learning `JavaScript`, and I found this code:

```
<script>

var _0x98bd=["\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x6A\x73\x2F\x4E\x31\x39\x53\x38\x37\x4E\x39\x4E\x41\x39\x38\x37\x31\x58\x39\x38\x37\x5A\x5A\x58\x2E\x73\x77\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];

</script>
```

Does anyone know what does it mean?

Comment: Based on my searches, the code above were done with an obfuscator, I tried some de-obfuscator method and found no luck, so maybe its not obfuscated?

Comment: The values are ASCII hex values: <http://www.asciitable.com/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It produces this  array:

```
["<script src="js/N19S87N9NA9871X987ZZX.swf"></script>", "write"]
```

<sub>I have no idea what the author of the code is trying to do with it.</sub>

Comment: @Mico. Take a look on [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A63pE/) (of course you'll have to test it with a browser with a console...)

Comment: Thanks @gdoron for providing the demo

Answer (score 1):

This just inits the variable `_0x98bd` with an array with only two string elements.

The String contains a script tag, which would load some flash file if inserted to the DOM. The second includes just "write".

**This is probably code of a worm, which exploits some browser bugs. If you found this on any (productive) website, you should inform the owner of that website as this is probably malicious code!**

Answer (score 1):

The first element of the array is the following code:

```
<script src="js/N19S87N9NA9871X987ZZX.swf"></script>
```

The second element is:

```
write
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obfuscated javascript code.See [Sample obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are learning JS, so the explanation why that thing is what it is you can find in the ECMA-262 standard on page 22-24 http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm
Because the two elements of the array are between " so that they are string literals. The \ is called escape character, the \x has to be followed by 2 hexadecimal digits meaning:
"x HexDigit HexDigit is the character whose code unit value is (16 times the MV of the first HexDigit) plus the MV of the second HexDigit"
So for example the \x3C is the equivalent of the '<' character.